# Module 'curl' already loaded on Xubuntu and Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, ubuntu

I'm having trouble getting Google App Engine to work on Xubuntu. I've installed PHP correctly, and it seems to be working with only two minor warnings. When I try to load the page, it is blank.

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Do you have any more information to give?

Answer (score 1):

These warnings would indicate that dynamic extensions are being loaded via .ini files, even though they are already loaded. It may also mean these extensions are being loaded multiple times.

Please edit your php.ini (or extensions.ini) file and comment-out the extensions that are already loaded.

http://www.somacon.com/p520.php